# PHP: Unset All Empty Key Value Pairs of an Array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

I have an associative array in my PHP code. I want to unset all the keys that have empty value.
I know individual keys can be unset using the following code

```
unset($array_name['key_name']);
```

What I don't know is how to recursively do this with an array. While searching for an answer I came across answers recommending PHP built-in function array_filter(), however I failed to grasp how that works. So here's the code I tried to write but it doesn't work either.

```
<?php
function unset_all_empty_array_keys($associative_array){
    foreach ($associative_array as $key => $value){
        if ($value == ""){
            unset($associative_array['$key']); // This doesn't work.
        }
    }
};

$list = array(
    "item1" => "one",
    "item2" => "",
    "item3" => "three",
);
unset_all_empty_array_keys($list, '$list');
print_r($list);

echo "<br>";

// Manually Unsetting key-value pair works fine.
unset($list['item2']);
print_r($list);
?>
```

Comment: There's no *recursion* here at all, it's just a single-dimensional array. The reason why nothing happens is that arrays are passed as copy, manipulating them in functions will not reflect to outside the function, unless you pass them *by reference.* But `array_filter` would pretty much do the job: `$list = array_filter($list)`…

Comment: @deceze I have tried passing array by reference but that too failed to do the job. Also I thought array_filter() must have a call back function as the second argument. Your solution worked like a charm. But still I would like to know how to do the same with foreach().

Comment: The callback is optional: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php#refsect1-function.array-filter-parameters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want do it with 'foreach()' then by reference:

```
function unset_all_empty_array_keys(&$associative_array){
    foreach ($associative_array as $key => &$value){
        if ($value == ""){
            unset($associative_array[$key]);
        }
    }
}
```

The way with 'array_filter()':

```
$list = array_filter($list,function($a){
    return $a!='';
})
```

And can only work 'recursively' on multi-dimensional array
`$a = ['a'=>['b'=>'']];`
Your example is an flat array with only one dimension.

So here the version for multi-dimensional arrays:

```
$list = array(
    "item1" => "one",
    "item2" => "",
    "item3" => array(
        "item1" => "one",
        "item2" => "",
        "item3" => "three",
    )
);


function unset_all_empty_array_keys_recursive(&$associative_array){
    foreach ($associative_array as $key => &$value){
        if ($value == ""){
            unset($associative_array[$key]);
        } else if (is_array($value)){
            unset_all_empty_array_keys_recursive($value);
        }
    }
}
unset_all_empty_array_keys($list);
var_export($list);
```